# How to check a value in a SQLite column is NULL or not with C API?

Tags: c, sqlite, null, null-check

I'm using SQLite with C API.
On C API, I can check the result value of a column with `sqlite3_column_*` functions. the problem is there is no function for the case of the value is `NULL`. Of course, I can check the value with `sqlite3_column_bytes` function, but it can cause conversion, and I want to avoid conversion at all.

How can I check the value at a column of a row is NULL or not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From what I can remember ([and tell from the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)), the correct way to do it is to use `sqlite3_column_type()` to check for `SQLITE_NULL`.

Just be sure to do it before doing anything that may cause conversion of the column.