# Equivalent of sqlite3_column_int to get possible NULL values

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

in my app, I am using a `SQLite` database to store some data. One of the integer fields is optional, so it is defined like so:

I have the following `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp FLOAT NOT NULL, testProperty INT);
```

I can get the float property using `sqlite3_column_double`. For the int column I could use 'sqlite3_column_int' but this always returns a value (0) even if the row does not contain a value.

How can I check if the row actually has a value for this property?

I have the following code to get all rows:

```
var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
let sql = "SELECT * FROM Test;"
   
sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.connection, sql, -1, &statement, nil)
    
while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW
{
  let testProperty = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2) // always returns 0
}
    
sqlite3_finalize(statement)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a value in a SQLite column is NULL or not with C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961457/how-to-check-a-value-in-a-sqlite-column-is-null-or-not-with-c-api)

Comment: Why did you delete your last question? If you undelete it I can post a solution if you haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3_column_type()` to check if it's `SQLITE_INTEGER` or `SQLITE_NULL`.